# SQL How to use info from created table

Tags: sql

```
SELECT yr, COUNT(title) AS g FROM movie 
JOIN casting ON id = movieid 
JOIN actor ON actorid = actor.id 
WHERE name = 'John Travolta'
AND g = 1
GROUP BY yr
```

--> I want g to work, but I don't know how to use info from same query.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.  Sample data, desired results, and a proper explanation really help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use g at that moment because you're trying to use an aggregate result before it's being aggregated. You need to use the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT yr, COUNT(title) AS g FROM movie 
JOIN casting ON id = movieid 
JOIN actor ON actorid = actor.id 
WHERE name = 'John Travolta'
GROUP BY yr
HAVING COUNT(title) = 1
```